# How can I make a Bootstrap 3 styled table to fill its rows when there's distinct columns count within?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I basically have a table which happens to get these sort of rows:

```
<tr>
    <td>H</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>L</td>
    <td>O</td>
    <td>!</td>
</tr>
```

So as I've added some visual classes like `.primary` or `.info` to each row and even got `.table-hover` table looks kinda strange.

[image]

In example above, last row got two columns and first one got only one. What should I do so the *smaller* table rows expand along the whole table width?

This is the html rendering (Jade) used to produce the same table in example:

```
.table-responsive
table.table.table-bordered.table-hover(style='max-width: none;')
    tbody                                                       
        tr(ng-show='beenEvaluated')
            th(colspan='4') Token re2
            th(colspan='4') Lexema
        tr(ng-repeat='(tokenRe2,lex) in re2Captures' ng-init='re2s = lex').info
            td(colspan='4') {{tokenRe2}}
            td(ng-repeat= 'i in lex track by $index' style='border:none;' colspan='4')
                li {{i}}
```

As it can be seen, I tried with colspan but got not results...

Comment: Can you clean up that code a bit? Maybe make a Bootply or JSFiddle example, cause what you posted now is hard to work with. An issue: You don't need `colspan` on EVERY item, only the ones that don't have enough columns in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `colspan`  attribute on the `<td>` tags.

```
<td colspan="2">H</td>
```

That will make the `<td>` two columns long. This can be applied to `<th>` tags as well, so use accordingly.

Hope that helps!

[See this Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/xvz7GDiAq1)

How colspan works:

```
+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

This is a table with the structure:

```
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
```

To make the table even, we'd add an extra `colspan` on the last `<th>` of the first row:

```
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th colspan="2"></th>
</tr>
```

So the table would look like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |         |
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    |    |    |
+----+----+----+----+
```

TL:DR `colspan` fills in space depending the other rows in the table. Use accordingly.

Comment: I tried it but got not results, thanks so far. Check my edits.